# Displaying foreign characters on the website

Tags: character

I have a small list in a foreign language and I am able to display the special foreign characters on the website I am updating. For example to display ü on the website, I write Ã¼ in the file. Or to display ö, I write Ã¶ in the file. And they are displayed correctly. So far no problems. But now I must also display the character β. Can you just write me the code for it in that same set? Or better yet, tell me where can I find the corresponding character? such as in a list? what is the name of the list I must look at? Again, I want to display character β on a website, by writing the corresponding special character on the source file, just like I am writing Ã¼ to display ü.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is what's happening, because your text editor use [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) to open and save the files, but your web server serve them to your user with [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). You can confirm it with https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx or other tools using encode set to ISO 8859-1 but the decode set to UTF-8.

The fix is to set your text editor to use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with the link you gave.